# Create a UIImageView subclass with a String tag?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to get a functionality in which when you set your image with a file, the `UIImageView` subclass will automatically save this in a `var stringTag:String!`

If I simply create the subclass with this var, I will have to manually set it's tag name when I set the image :

```
imageView.image ="abc.png"
imageView.tagString="abc.png"
```

Is there a simple way to create this subclass so when I set the image, it will save it's file name as a tag var automatically ?

Comment: Doesn't make sense because you can assign a UIImage to an imageView without it having a file name. IE: UIImage from NSData or UIImage downloaded. In those cases, it'll have no name.

Comment: That's right, so the class will never "know" automatically ? I will have to manually set this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. Because UIImage doesn't store any information about file path or name.

One way to achieve something similar to what you want is to do something like this:

```
class TaggableImageView:UIImageView
{
  var tagString:String?
  var imageName:String?
  {
    didSet
    {
      self.image = UIImage(named:imageName)
      self.tagString = imageName
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so didSet is what happen when you do imageView.image = x ? or is it something I have to set : imageView.imageName= x ?

Comment: `didSet` activates whenever you assign a new value to any property. There also exists `set`, `didGet`, and `get`